# Docker container get next: not found from docker-compose container

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having an issue with my docker-compose configuration file. My goal is to run a Next.js app with a docker-compose file.

This is my current DockerFile

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

and this is my Docker Compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend-flask:
    build: ./backend   
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code  

  frontend-fligh:
    build: ./frontend-fligh
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-fligh:/app
```

and my package.json with the next depencendcy

```
{
  "name": "fligh-next",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.3",
    "google-map-react": "^2.2.0",
    "next": "13.2.3",
    "photoswipe": "^5.3.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-input-range": "^1.3.0",
    "react-modal-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-multi-date-picker": "^3.3.4",
    "react-parallax": "^3.5.1",
    "react-photoswipe-gallery": "^2.2.6",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-tabs": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "swiper": "^8.4.7"
  }
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting

```
fligh-frontend-fligh-1  | yarn run v1.22.19
fligh-frontend-fligh-1  | $ next dev
fligh-frontend-fligh-1  | /bin/sh: 1: next: not found
fligh-frontend-fligh-1  | error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

To add my context, there is a working local directory of the same content with a node module installed with local yarn install commands, but when I pull from github running yarn install with dockerfile, with no inital node_module file this error occurs

[UPDATE] Resvoled the issue by deleting the volumes, but now hot reload doesnt work, any work arounds?

Comment: Can you share your whole `package.json` file?

Comment: The `volumes:` blocks are hiding everything in their respective images; the `RUN yarn install` has no effect because a mount hides the image's `node_modules` directory.  Does deleting both of the `volumes:` blocks in the Compose setup help?

Comment: @RobinThomas updated the file with the complete package.json

Comment: @DavidMaze Deleting the volumes worked but now it can't hot reload when I make changes